# d3 selection.exit().remove() not working, _exit is always array(0)

Tags: d3.js

I have gone through quite a few tutorial but still couldn't work out how to correctly update data, any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!

For some reason, the code doesn't run properly in the snippet, I am quite new to use it,
what I want to achieve is by clicking the button, the data got updated, I tried to use selection.exit().remove, but the exit array is always empty, I don't really understand how that works

```js
const arr = [{
    name: "A",
    dataset_1: 5,
    dataset_2: 6,
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    dataset_1: 7,
    dataset_2: 22,
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    dataset_1: 33,
    dataset_2: 23,
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    dataset_1: 20,
    dataset_2: 12,
  },
  {
    name: "E",
    dataset_1: 21,
    dataset_2: 15,
  },
  {
    name: "F",
    dataset_1: 15,
    dataset_2: 18,
  },
];
//function for adding dataset
let counter = 2;
const add_set = (arr) => {
  const ran = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
  const add = (arr) => {
    counter++;
    arr.map((i) => (i[`dataset_${counter}`] = ran()));
  };
  add(arr);
};
//function for removing dataset
const remove_set = (arr) => {
  arr.map((i) => delete i[`dataset_${counter}`]);
  counter >= 1 ? counter-- : counter;
};

//draw area chart
const draw = () => {
  //No.1 define place to draw
  let svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
      left: 50,
      right: 50,
      top: 15,
      bottom: 30
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"
    );
  //No.2 set axes
  let categoriesNames = arr.map((d) => d.name);
  let xScale = d3.scalePoint().domain(categoriesNames).range([0, width]); // scalepoint make the axis starts with value compared with scaleBand
  let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
  copy.map((i) => delete i.name);
  var yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(copy, (i) => Math.max(...Object.values(i)))]);
  let colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeSet3);
  let dataSets = Object.keys(arr[0]).filter((i) => i !== "name");
  colorScale.domain(dataSets);
  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
  g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
  g.exit().remove();
  //No.3 draw chart
  let areaData = dataSets.map((i) => {
    return {
      id: i,
      values: arr.map((d) => {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d[i]
        };
      }),
    };
  });

  let generator = d3
    .area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .y0(yScale(0))
    .x((d) => xScale(d.name))
    .y1((d) => yScale(d.value));
  let area = g
    .selectAll(".area")
    .data(areaData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", (d) => `area${d.id}`);
  area.exit().remove();
  area
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", (d) => {
      return generator(d.values);
    })
    .attr("opacity", 0.6)
    .style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.id));
};

//buttons
draw();
const update = () => {
  add_set(arr);
  draw();
};
const remove = () => {
  remove_set(arr);
  draw();
};
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .text("Remove dataset")
  .on("click", remove);
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .text("Add dataset")
  .on("click", update);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<html>



<body>
  <svg width="700" height="500"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of pasting the same sentence over and over, please explain more carefully how to reproduce, what to expect, and what goes wrong

Comment: sorry about repeating, stackoverflow ask me to write more words, ok I will add some more description

Comment: They ask you that because they think your question might need some more context, so they try to coach you to add a better description. You're not gaming a system, but reducing the quality of your own question by doing this

Comment: sorry about that, and thank you for the suggestion, would you be able to have a look at my code? I remember you are an expertO(∩_∩)O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selection.exit()` is empty, because `selection` is a subset of nodes from `g`, and `g` is newly added every time you call `draw`. You need to separate one-time logic (draw axes, append container elements, set height/width/etc) from logic you want to run each time.

You should also see in your code that the colour of one of the areas changed. That was because another area was drawn in front of it. If something was really wrong, it would have repurposed the existing areas and failed to remove the one you didn't need. This is a pointer that you append something the second time that you shouldn't have appended!

But there was more. You use `g.selectAll(".area")`, append a `g` element, but don't give it class `area`. Instead, you give it class `areadataset_1` and `areadataset_2`. This way, on subsequent calls, you can't find the area elements!

You also need to learn about `.merge()`. I recommend looking up some tutorials, like [this one](https://observablehq.com/@dnarvaez27/understanding-enter-exit-merge-key-function). You only updated the new paths, never the old ones. Since you didn't need `g`, I removed it for now, making the rest of the logic easier.

```js
const arr = [{
    name: "A",
    dataset_1: 5,
    dataset_2: 6,
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    dataset_1: 7,
    dataset_2: 22,
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    dataset_1: 33,
    dataset_2: 23,
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    dataset_1: 20,
    dataset_2: 12,
  },
  {
    name: "E",
    dataset_1: 21,
    dataset_2: 15,
  },
  {
    name: "F",
    dataset_1: 15,
    dataset_2: 18,
  },
];
//function for adding dataset
let counter = 2;
const add_set = (arr) => {
  const ran = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
  const add = (arr) => {
    counter++;
    arr.map((i) => (i[`dataset_${counter}`] = ran()));
  };
  add(arr);
};
//function for removing dataset
const remove_set = (arr) => {
  arr.map((i) => delete i[`dataset_${counter}`]);
  counter >= 1 ? counter-- : counter;
};

const margin = {
  left: 50,
  right: 50,
  top: 15,
  bottom: 30
};

let svg,
  width,
  height,
  g;

const setup = () => {
  //No.1 define place to draw
  svg = d3.select("svg");
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  g = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"
    );
}

//draw area chart
const draw = () => {
  //No.2 set axes
  let categoriesNames = arr.map((d) => d.name);
  let xScale = d3.scalePoint().domain(categoriesNames).range([0, width]); // scalepoint make the axis starts with value compared with scaleBand
  let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
  copy.map((i) => delete i.name);
  var yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(copy, (i) => Math.max(...Object.values(i)))]);
  let colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeSet3);
  let dataSets = Object.keys(arr[0]).filter((i) => i !== "name");
  colorScale.domain(dataSets);
  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
  g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
  g.exit().remove();
  //No.3 draw chart
  let areaData = dataSets.map((i) => {
    return {
      id: i,
      values: arr.map((d) => {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d[i]
        };
      }),
    };
  });

  let generator = d3
    .area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .y0(yScale(0))
    .x((d) => xScale(d.name))
    .y1((d) => yScale(d.value));
  let area = g
    .selectAll(".area")
    .data(areaData);
  area.exit().remove();

  area
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", (d) => `area area${d.id}`)
    .attr("opacity", 0.6)
    .merge(area)
    .attr("d", (d) => {
      return generator(d.values);
    })
    .style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.id));
};

//buttons
setup();
draw();
const update = () => {
  add_set(arr);
  draw();
};
const remove = () => {
  remove_set(arr);
  draw();
};
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .text("Remove dataset")
  .on("click", remove);
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .text("Add dataset")
  .on("click", update);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<html>



<body>
  <svg width="700" height="500"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know there are so many things that I should take care of, so I can use the same logic for the legend and axes? if I can't work them out, can I comment here again? and you can take a look?

Comment: Code in comments is not well supported, I'd ask a new question, but be sure to reduce it to a [mre](!)

Comment: sure, I hope I can work it out myself, or if the question is easy to describe don't need code can I comment here? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `selectAll` and `append` were using different types:

```
groups.selectAll('rect.bar-item')
///...
enter.append('path')
```

Making them the same `rect` or only `path` solved it for me.

Hope this helps someone.